# Flutter Circular Slider

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I'm using the Sleek_circular_Slider and was wondering if there is a way of changing the value/position of the slider from an external button press? I cant seem to see the value that it would be setting to change it.
Code:

```dart
Widget controlIndicator() {
    return SleekCircularSlider(
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        initialValue: 4,
        innerWidget: (value) {
          return sliderCenterWidget();
        },
        appearance: CircularSliderAppearance(
            spinnerMode: false,
            animationEnabled: true,
            size: 250,
            customColors: CustomSliderColors(
                dotColor: dark_grey,
                shadowColor: dark_grey,
                shadowMaxOpacity: 0.2,
                shadowStep: 5,
                progressBarColor: red,
                trackColor: grey),
            customWidths: CustomSliderWidths(
                trackWidth: 7, progressBarWidth: 12, handlerSize: 8)),
        onChange: (value) {
          slider_value = value.round();
          print(value);
        });
  }
```

Comment: can you add your code snippet so that it will be easier for us to find your error

Comment: I added the code, 
thanks for answering

Comment: you can make your initialValue change on button click using setstate should change your widget data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try to set the initialValue as a variable? then change this var value on button press